# Does level of bats activity differs from day to day?

Tags: ethology, mammals, experimental-design

Say we measure bats activity as number of passes through given area. Can it differ significantly depending from day to day or it stays on average roughly the same? I am wondering whether the following might have an effect:

- Weather conditions (wind or rain). I do not mean here heavy conditions (strong wind or rain), those understandably will affect bats eagerness to fly
- Moon cycle
- Mating
- For insect-easting bats: the prey not being active every night

I would welcome some good reading on the subject.

My question stems from the following problem. Say I have one detector and want to measure activity in three locations. If I rotate it between them, will I get unbiased result?